# Cannot call value of non-function type (declared as var)

Tags: ios, swift, migration, tuples, swift3

I migrated my project to Swift 3 and am down to 4 errors in an open source framework. The open source code is https://github.com/blackmirror-media/BMInputBox. It was working fine in Swift 2.2. It migrated fairly smoothly, with the exception of these errors. The errors are all the same and state:

```
.../Pod/Classes/BMInputBox.swift:430:26: 
Cannot call value of non-function type '((AnyObject...) -> Void)!'
```

Here's the code it relates to:

```
/// Closure executed when user submits the values.
open var onSubmit: ((_ value: AnyObject...) -> Void)!

/// As tuples are not supported in Objc, this is a method, which is called as well, but instead an array of values are returned
open var onSubmitObjc: ((_ value: [AnyObject]) -> Void)!

/// Closure executed when user cancels submission
open var onCancel: (() -> Void)!

/// Closure executed when the value changes in the field. The caller can modify the value and return it
open var onChange: ((_ value: String) -> String)?

func cancelButtonTapped () {
  if self.onCancel != nil {
    self.onCancel()
  }
  self.hide()
}

func submitButtonTapped () {

  // Submitting the form if valid
  if self.validateInput() {
    if self.onSubmit != nil {
      let valueToReturn: String? = self.textInput!.text

      if let value2ToReturn = self.secureInput?.text {
*Error>   self.onSubmit(valueToReturn, value2ToReturn)
      }
      else {
*Error>   self.onSubmit(valueToReturn)
      }
    }

    if self.onSubmitObjc != nil {
      let valueToReturn: String? = self.textInput!.text

      if let value2ToReturn = self.secureInput?.text {
*Error>   self.onSubmitObjc([valueToReturn!, value2ToReturn])
      }
      else {
*Error>   self.onSubmitObjc([valueToReturn!])
      }
    }

    self.hide()
  }

    // Shaking the validation label if not valid
  else {
    self.animateLabel()
  }
}
```

I'm new to Swift and am having trouble figuring out what this is actually supposed to do. Without knowing that, it's hard to figure out what Swift 3 doesn't like about it.

What does this line actually do?

```
open var onSubmit: ((_ value: AnyObject...) -> Void)!
```

To my inexperienced eyes, it looks like it's trying to pass a tuple to a function that is declared as a variable (rather than a function) and that doesn't do anything or return anything. I'm obviously missing something. Can anyone explain why it is declared as a variable and why there is no logic defined in it? If anyone knows why Swift 3 is complaining, that would be a bonus!

Comment: `onSubmit` is a variable holding a *closure* as an implicitly unwrapped optional. But the error message is misleading, the actual reason is that strings are no longer bridged to `AnyObject` automatically. – Replacing `AnyObject` by `Any` in those closure definitions might solve the problem.

Comment: Awesome! That did the trick. Thanks. It would have taken me forever to figure that one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onSubmit` is a variable holding a *closure* as an implicitly unwrapped optional. But the error message is misleading, the actual reason is that strings (numbers, etc) are not automatically bridged to `AnyObject` anymore in Swift 3.

Replacing `AnyObject` by `Any` (the protocol to which *all* types conform) in those closure definitions should solve the problem.